# Modify kwarg data for view in django

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I am trying to implement an MVC like pattern in my views.

Basically I have a base View which serves a normal type, and type1 view and type2 view that extends the base view.

I also have a controller and a model to get and set data. 
I need to pass this model over to the view. 
But I always get a KeyError when I access the kwargs dict from the view.

I am new to django and python. So please don't mind if I am missing something obvious.

Here is the code

```
class Controller():

    NORMAL, TYPE1 , TYPE2 = (0,1,2)

    @classmethod
    def controller_init(cls): #entry point to view. Called in urls.py
        def view(request,slug,*args,**kwargs):
            self = cls()
            self.request = request
            self.slug = slug
            self.args = args
            self.kwargs = kwargs
            return self.start()

        return view

    def start(self):
        modal = Modal()
        self.kwargs['modal'] = modal
        modal.init(self.slug)
        ptype = modal.getPtype()
        return self.showView(ptype) 

    def showView(self,viewType):
        if(viewType == self.NORMAL):
            view_handler = View1.as_view()
        elif(projectType == self.TYPE1):
            view_handler = ExtendedView1.as_view()
        else:
            view_handler = ExtendedView2.as_view()

        return view_handler(self.request,self.args,self.kwargs)
```

Here is my view :

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class View1(TemplateView):

template_name = "view_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(View1, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.modal = kwargs['modal']
        context['pid'] = self.modal.getPID()
        context['title'] = "This is a normal"
        return context
```

When I run the page, I get a KeyError saying the key modal is not defined.

Comment: Please update your answer to include the KeyError

Comment: your indentation is confusing please correct that so that scopes becomes clear

Comment: Why are you doing this? Django already provides an MVC pattern.

Comment: The MVC pattern Django provides doesnt allow me to extend views for a single url pattern. So I decided it was best to make a controller that does this. I could be wrong.